# Timesing by a negative switches the limits on an integral?

Tags: integration

I came across this new rule that I didnt know existed. If you times a definite integral by -1 does it switch the limits? As you can see below they times it by -1 and the limits go swtiched is that just a rule I should learn?

[image]

Comment: You know that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)- F(a)$. I guess you can take it from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Suppose $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=[F(x)]_a^b=F(b)-F(a),$$ then consider $$-\int_a^b f(x)\, dx=-[F(x)]_a^b=-[F(b)-F(a)]=F(a)-F(b)=\int_b^af(x)\,dx.$$ Hence we have proved that $$-\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_b^af(x)\,dx.$$